# Backbone.js: How to call methods on the collection within an object literal

Tags: model-view-controller, coding-style, backbone.js, underscore.js, object-literal

I have the following backbone.js code. I'm using an object literal for organizing my code, which has left me with a question regarding the best way to proceed. The application (in its simplified form below) has a control panel (which can be shown or hidden) which is used to add new categories to a collection. (Question follows)

```
(function($){

    // ============================= NAMESPACE ========================================
var categoryManager = categoryManager || {};

    // ============================= APPLICATION =================================================

categoryManager.app = categoryManager.app || {

    /* Used to Initialise application*/
    init: function(){
        //this.addView = new this.addCategoryView({el: $("#add-new-category")})
        //this.collection = new this.categoryCollection();
        new this.addCategoryView({el: $("#add-new-category")})
        new this.categoryCollection();
    },

    categoryModel:  Backbone.Model.extend({
        name: null
    }),

    addCategoryView: Backbone.View.extend({

        events: {
            "click #add-new-category-button.add" : "showPanel",
            "click #add-new-category-button.cancel" : "hidePanel",
            "click #new-category-save-category" : "addCategory"
        },
        showPanel: function() {
            $('#add-new-category-button').toggleClass('add').toggleClass('cancel');
            $('#add-new-category-panel').slideDown('fast');
        },
        hidePanel: function() {
            $('#add-new-category-button').toggleClass('add').toggleClass('cancel');
            $('#add-new-category-panel').stop().slideUp('fast');
        },
        addCategory: function() {
            //categoryManager.app.collection.create({
            categoryManager.app.categoryCollection.create({ // My Problem is with this line
                name: $('#name').val()
            });
        }
    }),

    categoryCollection: Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: this.categoryModel,
        initialize: function () {

        }
    })
}
    // ============================= END APPLICATION =============================================

    /* init Backbone */

    categoryManager.app.init();

})(jQuery);
```

Now obviously the problem with the above, is that calling the addCategory function tries to call a function on an object which is uninitialized. I've worked round the problem (see commented out code) by calling the function *instead* on a object which is instantiated within the init function. My question is - is this the right thing to do? I detect a code smell. I feel that the contents of the object literal shouldn't rely on the object being created in order to be valid. the function addCategory in this instance wouldn't work unless the init function had been called on the parent first. **Is there another pattern here that I should be using?**

How else would I pass the contents of the 'create new category form' to the collection in order to be added (I'm using create because I want to automatically validate/create/persist the model and It seems like the easiest thing to do). I'm a rock bottom novice with backbone (this is my 'hello world')

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue is you are treating `categoryCollection` as if it's an object. It's not really an object, but a *constructor function*. So first you need to create an instance, as you have discovered.

Then the `addCategoryView` needs some way of referencing the instance. It looks like you don't have a model associated with the view. I would suggest creating a model and storing the `categoryCollection` instance as a property of the model. Something like this (warning, untested code):

```js
var model = new BackBone.Model({
    categories: new categoryManager.app.CategoryCollection()
});

var view = new categoryManager.app.AddCategoryView({
    el: $("#add-new-category"),
    model: model
});
```

Then you can just use `this.model.categories` from inside `addCategoryView`.

As an aside, a common Javascript convention is to capitalize the names of constructors. Calling the constructor `CategoryCollection` might make the code a little bit clearer.

Comment: My understanding was that collections containted models and not the inverse. Is it OK (not o.k as in 'will work', but o.k as in 'the right thing to do') for a model to contain a collection which itself contains models (as my collection does)? Thanks for the input.

Comment: I think it's OK, and helps with encapsulation - the general idea of MVC-type architectures is that the model contains all the data the view needs to render itself.

Comment: Thanks - you'll see that I've stuck a bounty on this so I'm going to keep it open to see if I get some more answers. I couldn't get your code to work (the first line) so I did this instead. AddViewModel: Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
            this.categories = new categoryManager.app.CategoryCollection;
        },
        
        categories: null
    }). If I omit the initialize function it fails - I cannot directly assign the constructor to the 'categories' property.

Comment: The sample code wasn't quite right - hopefully it is better now

Comment: Nope - I get the following error if I try to directly initialise the collection. 'categoryManager.app is undefined'. If I initialise the collection within the initialise method of the model then it works as expected.

Comment: I've been working away on this been I'm now wondering - why do I need to pass the collection into a model before adding to the view. I can just add the collection straight to the view can't I?

Comment: Basically, separation of concerns. It's better to separate your data by putting it in a model, rather than setting values directly on the view. In the future you may end up with a big model with lots of data  - it will be easier to work with if you keep it separate from the view, rather than mixing it in with all the events and actions that are part of a view.

Comment: But my models (which contain the data) are part of a collection which itself is passed into a view - the concerns are still separated. Having a model that will only ever have one property (a collection) seems redundant to me - maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, they are both valid approaches. If you're sure the only data your view will need is the collection, then you can use the collection **as** the model. But in my mind one of the strengths of backbone views is reusability. Suppose you want several CategoryViews on one page, and you want them each to display different titles, and perhaps behave in slightly different ways when you select a category, for example. Then you'll need extra properties on the model to drive these behaviours - using a separate model gives you this kind of flexibility.

Comment: I'll keep that it mind - I'm sure its a situation 'll run into. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize collection before create a new instance of a model

```
addCategory: function() {
    var collection = categoryManager.app.categoryCollection;

    !collection.create && (collection = new collection);
    collection.create({
        name: $('#name').val()
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi. I already know that (see the lines in my code that have been commented out). What is the purpose of the third line of code in your example?

Comment: `!collection.create` check that `collection` is not initialized and if not it initializes collection and assign it to `collection` variable

Comment: `!collection.create && (collection = new collection);` equal to `if(!collection.create) { collection = new collection }`